# Replace/Overwrite wordpress plugin class function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to replace or overwrite an action hook declared inside a wordpress plugin class

```
class WCFM_Withdrawal {

    public function __construct() {
        global $WCFM;
            
            // WCFMu Thirdparty Ajax Controller
            add_action( 'after_wcfm_ajax_controller', array( &$this, 'wcfm_withdrawal_ajax_controller' ) );
            

        
    }
```

Here the add_action hook which points the function. I want to replace *"wcfm_withdrawal_ajax_controller"* with my own function.

```
add_action("init", function () {
    // removing the woocommerce hook
  global $WCFM;
    remove_action( 'after_wcfm_ajax_controller', array( $WCFM, 'wcfm_withdrawal_ajax_controller' ) );
});

add_action( 'after_wcfm_ajax_controller', 'my_new_function'  );

function my_new_function(){

  //Do something here
}
```

i have tried to remove_action and add my own function, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct Class instance. Your example shows `$WCFM`, but the class declaration is `WCFM_Withdrawal`. Is `$WCFM` an instance of `WCFM_Withdrawal`? If you have determined that you *do* have the appropriate class instance, you may be running the `remove_action` too early (before the one you want to remove is added).

You can try lowering the priority of your `init` function:

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
    // removing the woocommerce hook
    global $WCFM;
    remove_action( 'after_wcfm_ajax_controller', array( $WCFM, 'wcfm_withdrawal_ajax_controller' ) );
}, 99 );
```

I'd say you could also try a later Action Hook than init, but since this appears to be an AJAX handler, that probably won't suffice. Start by making sure that you've got the correct class instance variable, and then bump down the priority of your removal.

Comment: sorry i'm very new to php, however the class was decleared inside "../plugin-name/core/class-wcfm-withdrawal.php". I have tried declaring both `WCFM_Withdrawal ` & `WCFM ` and lowering the priority did'nt worked

Comment: No need to be sorry, we all start somewhere! Sorry I don't have more input for you, I've just had similar issues (wrong class instance and too high of a priority). I apologize I couldn't be more help. Have you tried reaching out to the WCFM team, or seeing if they have a support forum?